# BPMN modelling tool for nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

Which BPMN modelling tool should be used with Nodejs so that I can monitor process instances of that process as like JBPM in java and please suggest me example of that.

Comment: you mean something like pm2 or keymetrics??

Comment: I want to design business process using Node-js. so, I am not getting which module should be use for that

Comment: No not like pm2. means for example :- we write process in JBPM and combine that process in Java code just like that I want in Node-js.